# How to run Fast lane in terminal using php? exec() or shell_exec()

Tags: php

i was trying run fast lane commands in terminal using php, the commands like cd, pwd, ls and chmod working fine in php using exec or shell exec functions but when i try to run fast lane command it throws error 127, how can i run fast lane using php?

```
function terminal($command)
{
    $output = [];
    $return_var = '';
    //exec
    if (function_exists('exec')) {
         exec($command, $output, $return_var);
    } else {
        $output = 'Command execution not possible on this system';
        $return_var = 1;
    }

    return array('output' => $output, 'status' => $return_var);
}

// $path = "cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mystudiomobile/cordova7/platforms/ios/fastlane";
// $path_c = "fastlane init"; path and path_c present in test.sh
$command = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php1/test.sh";
$path_change = terminal("$command");

if($path_change['status'] == 0)
{
    echo json_encode($path_change['output']);
    echo $path_change['status'];
}
else
{
    echo "some problem";
    echo $path_change['status'];
}
```

Comment: Error `127` generally means that the system doesn't understand the command. That means it's not in the PATH and not a built in command. Make sure that the commands are in the PATH.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "fast lane"? Which parts of that code fail? If this is related to the underlying shell script, what have you tried to debug the sole execution of that script?

Comment: if i run the same .sh file script from terminal it runs perfectly fine but fails in php EXEC function,  fast lane is tool to upload builds to app store connect , if i could access fast lane via any of the server side script we could fully automate.  we prefer php

Comment: @NicoHaase Fastlane is a mobile app build and deployment automation tool. https://fastlane.tools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there are limitations in php to perform http and https protocols using system functions like exec. which could not run fast lane, the best practise is to go with bash script which access php instead of vice versa .